# Cannot Resolve the github repository

Tags: android, git, maven, github, gradle

Trying to use a repository which is available in **jetpack.io** and also is available through an aar file I've tried adding the module and its not working and now I am trying to add it using **jetpack repository**. here is my gradle file

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    mavenCentral()


}
dependencies {

    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0'
}
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
configurations {
all*.exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
}
dependencies {
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
compile 'com.github.QuadFlask:colorpicker:0.0.10'
}

android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion '23.0.1'


sourceSets {
    main {
        manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
        java.srcDirs = ['src']
        resources.srcDirs = ['src']
        aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
        renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
        res.srcDirs = ['res']
        assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
    }

    // Move the tests to tests/java, tests/res, etc...
    instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')

    // Move the build types to build-types/<type>
    // For instance, build-types/debug/java, build-   types/debug/AndroidManifest.xml, ...
    // This moves them out of them default location under src/<type>/...   which would
    // conflict with src/ being used by the main source set.
    // Adding new build types or product flavors should be accompanied
    // by a similar customization.
    debug.setRoot('build-types/debug')
    release.setRoot('build-types/release')
}
```

}

and the default repository is located here 
https://github.com/QuadFlask/colorpicker
when im trying to build my app it says cannot resolve the com.github. as the picture shows :

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to put the following into your root (project's) build.gradle file (not the module's build)

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
}
```